# Delete the relation between a product and a property group option

Tags: shopware, shopware6

Does anyone know a way to delete the relation between a product and a property group option using DAL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need to delete the corresponding `product_property` entity. The primary key is the productId combined with the (property group) optionId. So instead of providing an id with the delete, you provide the above attributes.

```
    $this->productPropertyRepository->delete([
        ['productId' => $data->get('product'), 'optionId' => $data->get('red')],
        ['productId' => $data->get('product'), 'optionId' => $data->get('green')],
    ], Context::createDefaultContext());
```